# How draw texture on Image (UI)

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, textures

I want draw renderer texture (which target texture for camera) to Image. But I dont`t understand how.

I try: Graphics.DrawTexture(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100), image), but its wrong.

Comment: A modicum of Googling led me to this Unity Answer: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/888246/use-a-rendertexture-in-a-gui-image.html

Comment: as Serlite says, use RawImage component and just drop the render texture to its texture slot.